# ES6 vs ES5 browser compatiable Array.Prototype.Includes and IndexOf

Tags: javascript

I have the below java script which seems to work fine in Chrome, Firefox but does not work in IE. I believe the problem is with array.prototype.includes vs array.prototype.indexof, however not sure how to fix this.

I believe it is the following line in the java script code causing the issue:

return memo.indexOf(index) > -1 ? getRandom(arr, memo) : index;

The snippet seems to display similarly to IE so you will see the issue. I have changed the code from ES6 to ES5 hoping this would work, however doesn't seem to fix the animation properly. The java script and html used in my code is posted below which should indicate the problem clearly. Seems to be an issue with the array but how it loops but cant figure out how to get it to display correctly using ES5 to it is compatible on all browsers.

```js
var mapping = {
  R:
    "1111111111111111111111000000111100000011110000001111111111101111111000110000110011000001101100000011",
  T:
    "1111111111111111111100001100000000110000000011000000001100000000110000000011000000001100000000110000"

};

// Grab the binary mapping of the letter and
function binaryise(letter) {
  var arr = mapping[letter].split("");
  return arr
    .map(function(char) {
      return (
        '<div class="' +
        (char === "0" ? "zero" : "one") +
        '">' +
        char +
        "</div>"
      );
    })
    .join("");
}

// For each letter in the word create a
// binary version and return it in a list-item container
function processWord(arr) {
  var items = arr
    .map(function(letter, i) {
      var binaryised = binaryise(letter);
      return (
        '\n      <li class="binaryli" data-id=' +
        i +
        '>\n        <div class="containerbinary">' +
        binaryised +
        "</div>\n      </li>\n    "
      );
    })
    .join("");
  return '<ul class="binaryul">' + items + "</ul>";
}

// Get a random number that hasn't previously appeared

function getRandom(arr, memo) {
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  return memo.indexOf(index) > -1 ? getRandom(arr, memo) : index;
}

// Once the html has been added to the page
// (all set with opacity to 0)
// iterate over the letters turning the
// opacity of each to 1
function showLetters(arr, memo) {
  memo = memo || [];
  if (memo.length !== arr.length) {
    var index = getRandom(arr, memo);
    var letter = arr[index];
    var el = document.querySelector('[data-id="' + index + '"]');
    setTimeout(function() {
      el.classList.add("show");
      memo.push(index);
      showLetters(arr, memo);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

var wordArr = "RT".toUpperCase().split("");

// Process all the letters of the word and add them
// to the page...
var html = processWord(wordArr);
output.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);

// ...then fade them in
showLetters(wordArr);
```

```html
        <section id="binary">
            <div id="contactbinary" class="containersbinary">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <div id="output">

                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
</section>
```

[image: Below output is what happens in IE]

[image: Below output of second image is what appears in chrome (correctly)]

Comment: Reading through your code to understand what the goal you're attempting to achieve here is actually quite difficult. I think it would greatly simplify your problem down if you were to generate a randomly sorted array at the beginning and then perform a simple iteration over that

Comment: It took me a while to get the above code working on some browsers but thought this was the best way to do it, proven now I am wrong. Not sure on the best way to re-write the java script to avoid this issue

Answer (score 1):

According to [this link](https://caniuse.com/#search=includes), `includes` is not supported by any version of IE.

However [you can still use `indexOf`](https://caniuse.com/#search=indexOf), so just test if its result of it is not null, or use a JS compiler like Babel to translate all your code to ES5.

You can find your 'ES5ed' code [here](https://babeljs.io/en/repl.html#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBAtiAOsEsB2BzCBeCBvAUBCASgFx74QBEAjNTbXfZQAzMu0us3vMNsMfvVuTAU0Fdq5ADSkAKiTIUeSzvy5C16jWLXbxwnfr3tyOHAF8A3KYD01iAHEwIAEYQALgAsAphGfJwAJ7QcIioEAD2AGbu3hAANl5ubl6QIEgAJjiRAK5IAMZuCOFIvv5gAQgAzl4AFAlJKQCU2KSgqWCQmDDwyCgA2vXJYAC6AHSVsHEIbjXk5I1W-GCJ2WAl4GCk-KPdNTn5hcU1eR7gzbgKSytrEDVblwDkADzpCMAQeXEglZXo5A8QADU9wUx1OnXQmHIjHIEAA_BQAF4pcKwogUYpeeZAkFkB7kAB8AOBlzIJ3AONJ-HIT2sr2ABJMpIW9zMjXuowAVuFkLN5lYzDY7AAxcKQLwgE7xRJDCDIGI-ADuYvSH2WIGSEBAOFspSQgQgwBSlSK6wyEGWblWJWmcvW8SqbgAtNMvFAPsU3CBkCksrkCqaILAwOE8l4fgB1FU1DbnVoU11QSoYLUdDm7fYBo6DFKSOVx0ltPWBKpeVWYPz68qluoypqLS6W623XH4B4AHRKlyeUw-Xx-f0rgSmsPSGpALvS6GJrbllKpDwJnapEBebz731-5Dynu9SBSQ_KhJnK8PFWqqpJVJpdLeS67ClpU3vCiZlxZCjZHO5vLmH4t1wlM82RxBuA7kGeIHHkCcrJEmME3iBjICkKDiJFqFppOk4Tukg2RQM4KQxBqECnJUSAPG4QbLMARTZJUcRBCEErLJkfoHIGKCJAQWE4TGHR5lAbrhAWhoJhkXgAB4pgAshqHijJEcThGKNRyZ4oxOBkfHNAAVKmYCjAkqCeP-TY3EJUDhKMyDpFJADykQ1LZUnNASEBOpQ8IQFxbg8dpUD8WAgnCc06IuZJKE6nY9n5D4ng-B4bhQKBZG-F4XjrOkdmqm44QKkGIBcdFtwgHEoHVFRirTB4ESwJK0xBHlECMOyuquk4mrhEakAJdKDRgMmVprL0ColeE9V5I1ETRBKUrNZQ7FZiUlQeOEioADJ1oNQUhVZomWflXTCRAAA-p0QH0wwNgg0Q1IdRmZSgngQAAhJCBmPSZHiifgRYRSmvn-dhgUbHtIkNn9FI5p0Bl9BF133EWXigZg2F5PhmVuKMACO2QpAEADKKNeAUqkPH0Y5epOfzEnadnSYCED4sMDz_vglUyAgQnhNkMyZocSA1L9ZAo6MnybhtjqjCA2WzKt638riD2wPRHjORJkns2QCubdtlS7dAoWQxAZh5vo_6CoKOBFsqYDpAAgh0KbkAQMjkKMeUAKrwCkADC3y1I04yTNMfIsiVAAKIZhj8WrlQVMPJlEBV26qWFatlCpQCVzV9fVXGjEXNsUklKUpsGobhpUUb2zUadO2ALK824qvY8g1RgG4DvpJykpYwAEjIMkbbMhGRGKGUZFIpHJXEEe6kXnveCUkSy_F3jusgOC61tA0Gw3HQLEAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)

Comment: I have used https://babeljs.io to compile my code but it doesnt seem to work still. My code is currently in ES5 but there is a problem with array.prototype.indexof. Not working the same way as array.prototype.includes as seen in the images

Comment: I used the online Babel to translate my code but it still doesn’t work

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with the css styling in IE rather than the JavaScript file. I converted from ES6 to ES5 but I didn’t know grids css styling which works in chrome does my work in IE

Comment: Oh right, though : https://caniuse.com/#search=grid it seems like putting `ms-` at the beginning of your CSS rule